# Using Underscore.js for case insensitive array filtering

Tags: javascript, filter, autocomplete, underscore.js, case-insensitive

How would you filter an array of strings making a full text search using `Underscore`?

I mean a filter that matches any quantity of characters, starting from anywhere in the string (not just from the beginning).

That function would be useful for an autocomplete feature.
For example, in a array of full names, looking for the middle name, or last name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `like` Underscore `mixin`. This function will compare strings using a regular expression (it is necessary to escape the regex special characters).

```
_.mixin({ 

  like: function(text, likeExpr) { 
    var regex = new RegExp(text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&'), 'i');
    return regex.test(likeExpr); 
  } 

});
```

This can be used as follows:

```
_.like('whatever', 'Something something WhaTEvEr something.'); // true
```

Then, you can use this function to filter an array:

```
_.filter(array, function(text) {
  return _.like('string to match', text);
});
```